# call JS function from external file on tab index change by user

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

i have in my .ascx file Image button that calls a Function from C# behind code 
Image button Code : 
`<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageItemThumb" runat="server" Width="75px" OnClick="switchTab_imgeClick" />`

and the Behind C# Function is

```
`
 protected void switchTab_imgeClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
           {
             TCArtistDetails.ActiveTabIndex = 2;
             ShowProjectDetails();
 //this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptInclude(this.GetType(),"showFunction","JScript1.js" );
         //Button imageFire = (Button)DataListCollection.FindControl("ImageClick");
         //imageFire.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "show");

         // Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), key, "<script type=\"text/javascript\">jQuery(window).load();</script>", true);
         // Dumy.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "Show");
         // string jScriptValidator;
         //jScriptValidator = "JQuery.switchTab_imgeClick";
         //Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "showFunction", jScriptValidator);
     }
```

`

and also there is the JS file that contain this Function

```
`
function show()
{
        alert("Hey Show ");
                    $('div.navigation').css({'width' : '200px', 'float' : 'right'});
                $('div.content').css('display', 'block');

                // Initially set opacity on thumbs and add
                // additional styling for hover effect on thumbs
                var onMouseOutOpacity = 0.67;
                $('#thumbs ul.thumbs li').opacityrollover({
                    mouseOutOpacity:   onMouseOutOpacity,
                    mouseOverOpacity:  1.0,
                    fadeSpeed:         'fast',
                    exemptionSelector: '.selected'
                });

                // Initialize Advanced Galleriffic Gallery
                var gallery = $('#thumbs').galleriffic({
                    delay:                     2500,
                    numThumbs:                 15,
                    preloadAhead:              10,
                    enableTopPager:            true,
                    enableBottomPager:         true,
                    maxPagesToShow:            7,
                    imageContainerSel:         '#slideshow',
                    controlsContainerSel:      '#controls',
                    captionContainerSel:       '#caption',
                    loadingContainerSel:       '#loading',
                    renderSSControls:          true,
                    renderNavControls:         true,
                    playLinkText:              'Play Slideshow',
                    pauseLinkText:             'Pause Slideshow',
                    prevLinkText:              '&lsaquo; previous ',
                    nextLinkText:              'next &rsaquo;',
                    nextPageLinkText:          'Next &rsaquo;',
                    prevPageLinkText:          '&lsaquo; Prev',
                    enableHistory:             false,
                    autoStart:                 false,
                    syncTransitions:           true,
                    defaultTransitionDuration: 0, // OMM , START , 8/1/2012 , Change From 900 to 0 
                    onSlideChange:             function(prevIndex, nextIndex) {
                        // 'this' refers to the gallery, which is an extension of $('#thumbs')
                        this.find('ul.thumbs').children()
                            .eq(prevIndex).fadeTo('fast', onMouseOutOpacity).end()
                            .eq(nextIndex).fadeTo('fast', 1.0);

                    },
                    onPageTransitionOut:       function(callback) {
                        this.fadeTo('fast', 0.0, callback);
                    },
                    onPageTransitionIn:        function() {
                        this.fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
                    }
                });
            };`
```

i wanna make this code run on the user click to the image the tab switch and run this JS script ??
all hashed lines i have tried but the page wont load 
Tip : Page refresh is not an Option :(

Comment: i have of course included the JS file in .ascx file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a hidden field in the page and on your code behind update this hidden field value by "1" for example to specify that the user did clicked on the tab then update your js code to be to run at the document ready event and check if the hidden field vale contains 1 or not and if it contains 1, then call your function.

Comment: 1- Cant be done here 
2- it already hit the JS Function as the Alerts Pop up ,, but the function result does not appear to be working in the page as it worked in the load at the first time

Comment: `<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageItemThumb" runat="server" Width="75px" OnClick="switchTab_imgeClick" onClientClick="show();" />` this make the alerts that in the function ,, but the function body does not work ?

Comment: Does the pop up appear first or the content ?! What i mean is that the pop up might work before the page content is loaded so when your js tries to get the html elements to work on, it didn't find any so you can check if the pop worked first or the page content loaded first.

Comment: pop up works first ,, and then load the page and the images as list ,, not gallery with slid show

Comment: So as i expected the js runs before anything is rendered so you need to call the function on the $(document).ready()

Comment: try this line of code in the code behind: Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), key, "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(document).ready(show());</script>", true);

Comment: I think the key can be an empty string